# Converting datatable - name/value data to columns

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable

Using VB.NET to do some funky data conversions ...

Have a .NET datatable that looks like this:

```
complex_ID              attr1Desc   attr1Value  attr2Desc   attr2Value  attr3Desc   attr3Value
00001-593-0000046772    yadda       22          hubba       892             
00001-593-0000046774                            blah        67
```

I need to transform it into:

```
complex_ID              yadda   blah    hubba
00001-593-0000046772    22              892
00001-593-0000046774            67
```

There are 30 "attr" column pairs. The data for any given record can be in any of them.

Looking for some elegant way to do this, in SQL, or LINQ ... not finding one. It's not really a pivot table (is it?).

Comment: Does the data come from a database?  If so, is it layed out as in the first part?

Comment: The most "elegant" way is probably simply the old fashioned way - create a new DataTable, and write your data row by row. Because this is not a true pivot table, any SQL or LINQ solution is likely to be either very complicated, slow, or both.